# EsendEx SMS Sending REST API Rich Content

Tags: c#, sms, rest

POST https://connect.esendex.com/richcontent/v3/send

Having been tasked to implement using EsendEx as a SMS provider and struggling to find working code on their site I am putting up a solution here.

This is Using the Rich Content API as that seemed the most flexible, although it does first require you to enable the provider on EsendEx and copy the subscription key.

This is the complete code required which I have also separated into classes for their request and response objects. You would probably want to copy these classes out into folders in your solution.

Hope this helps.

Sending an sms to the REST API will result in this call:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var smsProvider = new EsendexSmsProvider();
        
    var success = smsProvider.SendViaRichContentAsync( "Hello [[first_Name]], this is the voice of the Mysterons sending a test message").Result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace EsendExExample
{
    using EsendExExample.Request;
    using EsendExExample.Response;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var smsProvider = new EsendexSmsProvider();
            
            var success = smsProvider.SendViaRichContentAsync( "Hello [[first_Name]], this is the voice of the Mysterons sending a test message").Result;
        }
    }

    static class stuff
    {
        public static string ToBase64(this string plainTextToConvert)
        {
            var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainTextToConvert);

            return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Specific SMS sender implementation for Esendex SMS
    /// https://developers.esendex.com/
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class EsendexSmsProvider
    {
        private const string AccountRef = "EX0<number>";
        private const string Username = "someone@test.com";
        private const string ApiKey = "<yourkey>";
        private const string UserPassword = "<userpassword>";
        private const string RichContentEndPoint = "https://connect.esendex.com/richcontent/v3/send";

        // https://console.esendex.com/products/rich-content add subscription get key
        private const string RichContentSubscriptionKey = "<yoursubscription>";

        /// <summary>
        /// POST https://connect.esendex.com/richcontent/v3/send
        ///
        /// Authorization: YOUR_PRIMARY_KEY
        /// Content-Type: application/json
        ///
        /// https://developers.esendex.com/api-reference
        /// Example code founds at https://console.esendex.com/docs/services/Version-3/operations/Send
        /// </summary>
        public async Task<bool> SendViaRichContentAsync(string body)
        {
            var request = this.GetEsendexRichContentMessageRequest(body);
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);

            var httpResponse = await this.SendSms(json, RichContentEndPoint, RichContentSubscriptionKey);
            var responseBody = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var esendExResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EsendExMessageResponse>(responseBody);

            return httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode;
        }

        private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendSms(string message, string endPoint, string subKey)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            try
            {
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, endPoint)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent(message, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
                };

                var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", subKey);

                response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }

            return response;
        }

        private EsendexRichContentMessageRequest GetEsendexRichContentMessageRequest(string body)
        {
            return new EsendexRichContentMessageRequest
            {
                AccountReference = AccountRef,
                Channels = new List<string> {"SMS"},
                Metadata = new EsendexRichContentMetadata
                {
                    Key = "blah"
                },
                Recipient = new EsendexRichContentRecipient
                {
                    Variables = new EsendexRichContentVariables
                    {
                        ["first_Name"] = "Paul"
                    },
                    Address = new EsendexRichContentAddress
                    {
                        msisdn = "+44<number>"
                    }
                },
                ChannelSettings = new EsendexRichContentChannelSettings
                {
                    Sms = new EsendexRichContentSms
                    {
                        Originator = "John Doe",
                        CharacterSet = "GSM"
                    }
                },
                Content = new EsendexRichContentContent
                {
                    Body = new EsendexRichContentBody
                    {
                        Text = new EsendexRichContentText
                        {
                            Value = "Hello [[first_Name]], this is the voice of the Mysterons sending a test message"
                        }
                    }
                },
                Expiry = "30"
            };
        }
    }
}

namespace EsendExExample.Request
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;

    /// <summary>
    /// Serializing class for sending message to EsendEx rest API for messages
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>
    /// {
    /// "accountReference":"EX0000000",
    /// "messages":[{
    ///     "to":"447700900123",
    ///     "body":"Every message matters!"
    /// }]
    /// }
    /// </example>
    public class EsendExMessageRequest
    {
        [JsonProperty("accountReference")]
        public string AccountReference { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("messages")]
        public ICollection<EsendExMessage> Messages { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class EsendExMessage
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the phone number/ recipient identifier to send the message to
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty("to")]
        public string To { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the message to be sent in the SMS
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty("body")]
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class EsendexRichContentAddress
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the address id, or more frequently the Internationalised phone number.
        ///
        /// E.164 MSISDN Format
        /// The telephone number of the message recipient must be in E.164 format. This means the number must be in the format:
        ///
        /// +{Country Dial Code}{Rest of phone number}
        /// Examples
        ///
        /// Phone Number Country   Dial Code    E.164 Formatted Number
        /// 07948751633  UK         44          +447948751633
        /// 0123456789   France     33          +33123456789
        /// 912345678    Spain      34          +34912345678
        /// 0491570156   Australia  61          +61491570156
        /// 5417543010   USA        1           +15417543010
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty("msisdn")]
        public string msisdn { get; set; }
    }

    public class EsendexRichContentBody
    {
        [JsonProperty("text")]
        public EsendexRichContentText Text { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class EsendexRichContentChannelSettings
    {
        [JsonProperty("sms")]
        public EsendexRichContentSms Sms { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class EsendexRichContentContent
    {
        [JsonProperty("body")]
        public EsendexRichContentBody Body { get; set; }
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Serializing class for sending message to EsendEx rest API for messages using rich content SMS/pictures/whatsapp
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>
    ///     {
    ///     "accountReference": "{ESENDEX_ACCOUNT_REFERENCE}",
    ///     "channels": [
    ///     "SMS"
    ///     ],
    ///     "metadata":{
    ///     "key": "value"
    /// },
    /// "recipient": {
    ///     "variables": {
    ///         "name": "Fred"
    ///     },
    ///     "address": {
    ///         "msisdn": "{INTERNATIONALISED_PHONE_NUMBER}"
    ///     }
    /// },
    /// "content": {
    ///     "body": {
    ///         "text": {
    ///             "value": "Hello [[name]]"
    ///         }
    ///     }
    /// },
    /// "channelSettings": {
    ///     "sms": {
    ///         "originator": "{MESSSAGE_ORIGINATOR}",
    ///         "characterSet": "GSM"
    ///     }
    /// },
    /// "expiry": "30"
    /// }
    /// </example>
    public class EsendexRichContentMessageRequest
    {
        [JsonProperty("accountReference")]
        public string AccountReference { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("channels")]
        public List<string> Channels { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("metadata")]
        public EsendexRichContentMetadata Metadata { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("recipient")]
        public EsendexRichContentRecipient Recipient { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("content")]
        public EsendexRichContentContent Content { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("channelSettings")]
        public EsendexRichContentChannelSettings ChannelSettings { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("expiry")]
        public string Expiry { get; set; }
    }

    public class EsendexRichContentMetadata
    {
        [JsonProperty("key")]
        public string Key { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class EsendexRichContentRecipient
    {
        [JsonProperty("variables")]
        public EsendexRichContentVariables Variables { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("address")]
        public EsendexRichContentAddress Address { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class EsendexRichContentSms
    {
        [JsonProperty("originator")]
        [MaxLength(11)]
        public string Originator { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("characterSet")]
        public string CharacterSet { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class EsendexRichContentText
    {
        [JsonProperty("value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Used to st up any variables that can be used in the message via substitution.
    ///
    /// https://developers.esendex.com/api-reference#recipient-variables
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>
    /// {
    ///     "recipient": {
    ///     "variables": {
    ///     "first_name": "John",
    ///     "last_name": "Smith"
    /// },
    /// "address": {
    ///     "msisdn": "+447123456789"
    /// }
    /// },
    /// "content": {
    ///     "text": "Hello [[first_name]] [[last_name]]"
    /// }
    /// }
    /// </example>
    public class EsendexRichContentVariables : Dictionary<string, string>
    {
    }
}

namespace EsendExExample.Response
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;

    /// <summary>
    /// The accepted response from the Esendex SMS REST API call. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>
    /// {
    ///  "batch": {
    /// "batchid": "19aafc9c-b08a-400d-a9f1-afe3c46f0a25",
    /// "messageheaders": [
    /// {
    /// "uri": "http://api.esendex.com/v1.0/messageheaders/72d91006-eb01-4e69-ae98-0e02c92c8e34",
    /// "id": "72d91006-eb01-4e69-ae98-0e02c92c8e34"
    /// }
    /// ]
    /// },
    /// "errors": null
    /// }
    /// </example>
    public class EsendExMessageResponse
    {
        [JsonProperty("gatewayId")]
        public Guid GatewayId { get; set; }
        
        public EsendExResponseBatch Batch { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("errors")]
        public ICollection<EsendExResponseError> Errors { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class EsendExResponseBatch
    {
        [JsonProperty("batchid")]
        public string BatchId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("messageheaders")]
        public Collection<EsendExResponseMessageHeader> MessageHeaders { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class EsendExResponseError
    {
        [JsonProperty("code")]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("error")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public class EsendExResponseMessageHeader
    {
        public string Uri { get; set; }

        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```